# Is it possible to read/edit shared preferences in native code?

Tags: android

I have an Android app that includes a C library using NDK to execute some some code. Within the C library I would like to update the applications shared preferences. My question... is it possible to read/edit shared preferences in native code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do anything you want in native code. It's just cumbersome - you need the JNIEnv object to first find the class ID, then the method ID, if you have any non-primitive types, you need to create those too. But then you just call the method, and you're done.

[JNI Docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html) - look for `FindClass`, `GetMethodId`, `CallVoidMethod`, etc.